# Iterating around all the values in color.xml in android

Tags: android, loops

I'm developing an image editing app for android and would like to provide a list of defined colors for my users to choose from when doing certain activities (choosing an ink color etc)

I have a nice list of colors in my color.xml that is perfect for this task but I'm at a loss at how to iterate through it and pass it to a custom ListAdapter.

I've googled around but not really found any solutions to this.

Is there any way to just loop round all the values in color.xml?